# Expression: "To wish sb./sth. at the devil" meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrases, archaicisms

"Sancho Panza, who was wishing the goatherd's loquacity at the devil,..."

Context:
The goatherd was relating a lengthy story to Don Quixote, it was late at night and Sancho Panza, Don Quixote's squire, has had quite enough of it himself wanting to go to sleep...

I understand this expression must be archaic and not currently in use, can anyone provide a precise meaning and/or any synonymous expressions/words

Comment: Original in Spanish is "_dar al diablo"_...the actual quote was ["_Sancho Panza que ya daba al diablo el tanto hablar del cabrero,_"](https://www.elmundo.es/quijote/capitulo.html?cual=12)  AFAIK, the expression is not in use in Latin America, but is understood. It may still be in use in Spain. More common nowadays is "_mandar al diablo"_.

Comment: I've never heard the given expression used in English.

Comment: @KillingTime, you've probably heard a relative, though: "To the Devil with you!".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED gives the following definition:

> **to wish (a person) at (also †to, †unto) the devil**: to wish (a person) to be damned or ruined. Now *rare* or in historical contexts.

Comment: I've never heard it as "at", but I recognized "to".